# counting values in a dictionary Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
a = {bob:home, amy:school, george:school, Noah:school, Lilian:home}
```

i'm trying to get this output:

number of people staying home is 2

number of people going to school is 3

please help

```
def counting(x):
  homecount: 0
  schoolcount: 0
for i in x.key:
   if i == home:
    homecount += 1
   else:
    schoolcount +=1
print (f' number of people staying home is {homecount} ')
print(f' number of people going to school is {schoolcount}')
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i just edited it and added my code

Comment: `for i in x.values():` will help fix your code.

Comment: Thank you soo much about to try it now !

Comment: There are other errors: `homecount: 0` should be `homecount = 0`. Same for `schoolcount`. Also, `home` is a string and should be in quotes unless you defined a variable `home` elsewhere.

Comment: omg yes !! i'm supposed to know all this ! so silly of me ! THANK you so much for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, including that some of the syntax is not valid Python.

```
def counting(x):
    homecount = 0
    schoolcount = 0
    for val in x.values():
        if val == "home":
            homecount += 1
        elif val == "school":
            schoolcount += 1
        else:
            continue
    print(f"The number of people staying home is {homecount}")
    print(f"The number of people going to school is {schoolcount}")

counting(a)
The number of people staying home is 2
The number of people going to school is 3
```

1. To declare a variable use `=` not `:`.
2. You want to iterate over `values` not `keys`.
3. When comparing equality of values in your case, you have to use a "home" as a string, not a literal variable.
4. Don't use `else` in this case without an `elif` because you can get wrong counts if the dictionary has values besides `home` and `school`.

Comment: may i ask why is it important to add the else statement there please? it always confuses me

Comment: because if the `value` is not `"home"` or `"school"` we want to continue the loop without doing anything else. we can't always be sure that the data will contain _only_ those two values

Comment: You can remove `else: continue`. It is not needed here.

Comment: ooooh makes every sense! thank you so much guys, you are super helpful

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it is not needed but for a beginner it is better to be _verbose_ so that they understand/learn. they can take shortcuts in the future once they have a better grasp

Comment: @gold_cy That's why I prefer this answer to the others. Comprehensions and the stdlib are nice but without the basics you're not going to know where they apply.

Answer (score 1):

the answer could be expressed using a sum.

i.e.

```
home_sum = sum([x=="home" for x in a.values()])
school_sum = sum([x=="school" for x in a.values()])
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers a perfectly fine, but you might also want to check out `collections.Counter` as it does a lot of the work for you in situations like this:

```
import collections

data = {"bob":"home", "amy":"school", "george":"school", "Noah":"school", "Lilian":"home"}
the_count = collections.Counter(data.values())

print(f'staying home: { the_count.get("home") }')
print(f'going to school: { the_count.get("school") }')
```

Gives you:

```
staying home: 2
going to school: 3
```